# regular expression for language of phone numbers in 3 formats

Tags: regex

Suppose you have users who are entering 10 digit phone numbers in several formats, such as

```
xxxxxxxxxx, 
xxx-xxx-xxxx, 
(xxx)xxx-xxxx.
```

Write a regular expression for this language. Hint: you may want to separate different formats with a union ?

I came up with this expression

```
\d{10} U \d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4} U (\d{3})\d{3}-\d{4}
```

Any comments whether the above expression is correct for the problem?

Comment: Have you tried testing various input strings against the regular expression you have?

Comment: No is there an online regex to check?

Comment: What is `U` - is that like `|` ? - and regex101.com is excellent.

Comment: `U for union` - is that your own invention, or is there a dialect of regex that uses that?

Comment: own invention . cam to know that have to use | instead of U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://regex101.com/r/tK6mD4

```
(\d{10})|(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})|(\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{4})
```

Using `|` for "OR", no spaces, escaping the `()` with `\`.

Tested with

```
(888)123-3456     - match
8881231234        - match
888-123-1234      - match
888-1234567       - no match
```

Note - this expression matches exactly (and only) what you asked for. A good regex for "all valid phone numbers" is quite different - you can google that and will find a ton of answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this:

```
\(?\b[0-9]{3}\)?[-/\s]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}\b
```

Which would catch all of these formats:

```
XXXXXXXXXX
XXX-XXX-XXXX
(XXX) XXX-XXXX
(XXX)XXX-XXXX
(XXX) XXX XXXX
XXX/XXX-XXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

From 
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/advanced-regular-expression-tips-and-techniques/

```
/^(1[-\s.])?(\()?\d{3}(?(2)\))[-\s.]?\d{3}[-\s.]?\d{4}$/


    (1[-\s.])?  # optional '1-', '1.' or '1' 
    ( \( )?     # optional opening parenthesis 
    \d{3}       # the area code 
    (?(2) \) )  # if there was opening parenthesis, close it 
    [-\s.]?     # followed by '-' or '.' or space 
    \d{3}       # first 3 digits 
    [-\s.]?     # followed by '-' or '.' or space 
    \d{4}       # last 4 digits
```

This is specifically for US phone numbers - so also takes into consideration country prefix.